# Unable to declare a module "cannot declare a new module at this location"

Tags: rust

I have 3 files: lib.rs, file2.rs and file3.rs. I lib.rs I have this:

```
mod file2;
use file2::Struct2;
```

and it's working well. However, doing the same thing in file3 compiles with an error:

```
mod file2;
use file2::Struct2;

=> error: cannot declare a new module at this location
```

And if I remove mod `file2` declaration I get this:

```
error: unresolved import `Struct2`
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure why you're getting that error exactly, but that's not going to do what you want. Modules form a tree structure, and you use mod declarations to form them. So you're trying to create another file2 mod inside the file3 one.

I'm guessing you want file2 and file3 to both be under the main module, not sub modules of each other. To do this, put

```
mod file2;
mod file3;
```

In lib.rs, and then in file3.rs

```
use file2::Struct2;
```

And it should all work. I'm on mobile, so I can't triple check myself, sorry about formatting.

Comment: working. is the "lib.rs" special because it does allow to use "mod"s in it?

Comment: Nope, it's just the root of the tree. Also known as the 'crate root.' See the 'crates and modules' chapter of the book for elaboration.

Comment: that's what I'm saying "Is it special?" Being the root of the tree means yes.

Comment: It is NOT special in that it's the only place mod can go. They can go in any of these files.

Comment: @imatahi, please read the [chapter on modules](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/crates-and-modules.html) in the official book, it should give you some answers. `mod` declarations can be present in a any module; they only have to be used correctly.

Comment: mod declarations that create modules whose definition is in another file can only be created in the `lib.rs` due to the file system's tree structure being used in that case. Since a file cannot have "sub-files", you cannot create a mod declarations that requires another file.

Comment: @ker, so since **mod declarations that create modules whose definition is in another file can only be created in the lib.rs** we can say "lib.rs is a special file" in that sense, can't we?

Comment: That's also not true, as the actual error message says "maybe move this module `foo` to its own directory via `foo/mod.rs`" . That's also a module whose definition is in another file.

Comment: yes, `mod.rs` also allows this, since it's the "root-node" of a sub-tree that uses the file-system's tree structure.

Comment: I have a similar case to this. I can only use mod mod_a; once, in main.rs. Then for any other files that want to use mod_a, I have to use "use mod_a" or else I get the error about redeclaring the module. Why can't I use the same syntax to access another module no matter where I'm using it?

Comment: Matt, mod declares a module, use brings a name into a scope. So you can't declare it twice.